# Copy and paste from multiple Finder windows at once?

Tags: finder, windows, copy-paste

I have a very specific use case where I would like to gather video and audio files as revealed in the Finder. When I run a reveal in Finder command in Final Cut Pro it reveals multiple items in the Finder across multiple windows. They are all selected and able to be copied once I select the window - so at the moment the workflow is to one at a time go through each window and copy then past to the single destination folder.

My question is, is there any way - either in Finder, in Terminal, Automator, AppleScript, or a third-party app that I could copy all selected files across all windows at once, so I can then paste them in one single step?